# How to copy all the content of an Internet mime message to a body item in Notes?

Tags: java, email, lotus-domino, mime

I need to copy the entire body content of an Internet mail to a new Notes document.

```
Object internetMsgBody = internetMsg.getContent();

MIMEEntity notesBodyItem = notesDocument.createMIMEEntity("Body");
Stream mimeStream = dominoSession.createStream();
...?...
notesBodyItem.setContentFromBytes(mimeStream, msgContentType, 
MIMEEntity.ENC_NONE);
```

The internetMsgBody can be String, MimeMultiPart or InputStream (according to the documentation). I know how I can handle String :) but for the other Object types, I need some help. There is no need for any MIME or Parts content type handling.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe Session.setConvertMIME(true) may help https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_ISCONVERTMIME_PROPERTY_JAVA.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notes, a multi-part MIME message is represented as a set of items of the same name (usually `Body`) each of which is `TYPE_MIME`. Think of a `MIMEEntity` instance as corresponding to a single one of these items. In other words, a `MIMEEntity` represents a single MIME part.

So if your input is a multi-part MIME message, you may have to parse the message into individual parts and create a `MIMEEntity` for each. Unfortunately, the Java back-end classes don't include a MIME parser. Of course, your question states that `internetMsg.getContent()` *may* return a `MimeMultipart`. If that's the case, it sounds like the MIME is already parsed for you.

Either way -- whether your input is a stream of many parts or a `MimeMultipart` -- I suggest you look at [MimeMessageParser.java](https://github.com/OpenNTF/XPagesExtensionLibrary/blob/master/extlib/lwp/product/runtime/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.domino.commons/src/com/ibm/domino/commons/mime/MimeMessageParser.java) from the XPages Extension Library. It uses mime4j to parse an input stream. If there are multiple parts in the stream, it uses `MIMEEntity` to write each part as a separate item. Although the use of mime4j doesn't sound relevant, you may find some useful hints in that code. It implements a very similar use case.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Dave, you pointed me to the missing part. My solution (so far) is to create a parent Domino MIMEEntity which holds all MIME Parts as children.

Code excerpt:

```
MimeMultipart mimeMultiparts = (MimeMultipart) message.getContent();
int partCount = mimeMultiparts.getCount();
MIMEEntity dominoParentItem = mailDocument.createMIMEEntity("Body");
Stream dominoStream = dbGetSession().createStream();    

for (int counter = 0; counter < partCount; counter++) {
  MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart = (MimeBodyPart) mimeMultiparts.getBodyPart(counter);
  MIMEEntity dominoChildItem = dominoParentItem.createChildEntity();

  InputStream input = mimeBodyPart.getRawInputStream();

  byte[]    buffer      = new byte[4096];
  int       lengthTotal = 0;
  int       length      = 0;

  while (true) {
    length = input.read(buffer);
    if (length < 1)
      break;
    lengthTotal += length;
    dominoStream.write(buffer);
  }

  String encodingType   = mimeBodyPart.getEncoding();
  int dominoEncoding    = MIMEEntity.ENC_NONE;

  if (encodingType != null) {
    if (encodingType.toLowerCase().contains("base64"))
      dominoEncoding = MIMEEntity.ENC_BASE64;
    if (encodingType.toLowerCase().contains("7bit"))
       dominoEncoding = MIMEEntity.ENC_IDENTITY_7BIT;
    if (encodingType.toLowerCase().contains("8bit"))
       dominoEncoding = MIMEEntity.ENC_IDENTITY_8BIT;
    if (encodingType.toLowerCase().contains("binary"))
       dominoEncoding = MIMEEntity.ENC_IDENTITY_BINARY;
    if (encodingType.toLowerCase().contains("quoted-printable"))
       dominoEncoding = MIMEEntity.ENC_QUOTED_PRINTABLE;

    if (dominoEncoding == MIMEEntity.ENC_NONE)
       dominoEncoding = MIMEEntity.ENC_EXTENSION;
  }

  dominoChildItem.setContentFromBytes(dominoStream, mimeBodyPart.getContentType(), dominoEncoding);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up on this problem:

I came up with a much easier and more elegant solution. There is a writeTo() method which streams-out all the multipart data. This can then be streamed in again to a Domino stream which fills in the MIMEEntry body item.

```
case "javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart": {

    // Create input stream with content of MIME data
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    message.writeTo(outputStream);
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
    outputStream.close();

    // Create Domino stream and fill it with the MIME data
    Stream dominoStream = dbGetSession().createStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int lengthTotal = 0;
    int length      = 0;

    while (true) {
        length = inputStream.read(buffer);
        if (length < 1)
            break;
        lengthTotal += length;
        dominoStream.write(buffer);
    }

    inputStream.close();

    // Create Domino MIME "Body" item with content of MIME data
    MIMEEntity dominoMIMEItem = mailDocument.createMIMEEntity("Body");
    dominoMIMEItem.setContentFromBytes(dominoStream, "", MIMEEntity.ENC_NONE);
}
```